# D3.js: Drawing rectangles underneath text

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am working on a radial collapsible tree in using d3.js. Here is how it looks so far: [image]
As you can see highlighted in red is the fact that text overlaps the links. I would like the text to be "highlighted" in the background color, so that the links will not appear where the text is.

So far, I have tried highlighting the text using **background-color** in CSS and in .style() of the text.

```
.node text {
background-color: yellow;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
```

I have also tried **drawing a rectangle** of the size of the text before drawing the text, as seen in Mike Bostock's [bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714). However, when I execute the code, the rectangles are nowhere to be found, even in the source code via chrome's developer tool (there is a `<circle>` tag for the circles, but no rectangle tag).

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h05r2w6d/) of part of the code. I have made the rectangle in yellow in the CSS to see better in case it works, though I haven't been able to make it work.

The code of the rectangles are the following:

```
.node rect {
    fill: yellow;
}

nodeEnter.select("rect")
      .attr("height", 15)
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length + 50)  + ")"; })
      //.style("fill","yellow")
;
```

and

```
nodeUpdate.select("rect")
      .attr("height", 15)
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length + 50)  + ")"; })
      //.style("fill","yellow")
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `append` the rectangle in the enter selection, not `select`ing it:

```
nodeEnter.append("rect")
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wLwn9p98/

Comment: Thank you, now I feel stupid for missing that in the first place... Have you changed anything else? the rectangles seem to fit in the fiddle, but not in my actual code, and there is not much different there.

Comment: Yes, I changed the sizes of the rectangles.